# The message from Azure IoT hub is reaching partially to Stream Analytics and thereby SQL db

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-edge

The message from Azure IoT edge device installed on Raspberry Pi is sent to the cloud.
In the logs of IoT edge device on Azure Portal the message sent to the cloud is seen (in the troubleshoot section).
In the Stream Analytics the input is referring to IoT hub, the connection is valid.
In the Query section of Stream Analytics when loading the received message content some part of the message is lost. However, the message sent to the cloud from the device is full.
Is there any way to see where the message is lost?
Is the to make a query before stream analytics to find out the data type maybe?

Comment: What tutorial or the documentation you are following to integrate Azure IoTHub and Stream Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

We have to investigate this much more deeper, but i have few suggestions to look at this issue, sharing as below, helping with initial query...!

Try this sample query that you can use to check the message flow from the IoT Edge device to the Stream Analytics job:

```
IoTHub
| where DeviceId == "your_device_id"
| join (
    StreamAnalytics
    | where JobName == "your_stream_analytics_job_name"
) on IoTHub.MessageId == StreamAnalytics.InputMessageId
| project TimeGenerated, DeviceId, IoTHub.MessageId, StreamAnalytics.InputMessageId
```

Try below query to check the data type of the messages being sent from the IoT Edge device:

```
IoTHub
| where DeviceId == "your_device_id"
| project TimeGenerated, DeviceId, MessageId, json_tostring(Properties) as Properties
```

I prefer to use "[Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-live-data-local-testing)" feature in the Stream Analytics query section to see if it processes the message as expected.